# How to print unique values of a column in a group using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to print unique values of the column `ADO_name` in my data set. Following is the example data set and code I tried (which gives error):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

data = {'ADO_name':['car1','car1','car1','car2','car2','car2'],
        'Time_sec':[0,1,2,0,1,2],
        'Speed.kph':[50,51,52,0,0,52]}
dframe = DataFrame(data)


for ado in dframe.groupby('ADO_name'):
  ado_name = ado["ADO_name"]
  adoID = ado_name.unique()
  print(adoID)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Quinton\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp88ifpB\chunk-code-188c39fc7de8.txt", line 14, in <module>
    ado_name = ado["ADO_name"]
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it? Please help.

Comment: print(dframe.ADO_name.unique())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to correct your code or use the correct way.

Here is what you need to correct in your code.

```
for ado in dframe.groupby('ADO_name'):
    ado_name = ado[1]["ADO_name"]
    adoID = ado_name.unique()
    print(adoID)
```

Comment: Why is `[1]` needed here?

Comment: groupby method returns a tuple with first element as the group name and second element is the Dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

You can do: `dframe["ADO_name"].unique()`.

Comment: This one is clean.